# NativeScript-Vue with Material design

Tags: vue.js, material-design, nativescript

I'm interested with vue.js and nativescript, but I'm not sure how to produce material designed apps. This is due to, that I am not really sure how the vue-nativescript works. I have found this well documented [vuematerial.io](https://vuematerial.io/) and I have been wondering, if I can use this for mobile app.

Is it possible to use it in nativescript or is it targeted only on mobile web pages?

If no, is there any way how to force to render vue-nativescript app in Material design?

Comment: I never used it but i think this looks promising because you can compile this into native and web targets: http://quasar-framework.org/

Comment: Nice framework, but actually im about to use [https://www.nativescript.org/](https://www.nativescript.org/) and [integration with vue](https://github.com/nativescript-vue/nativescript-vue)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you rightly understood what NativeScript is, a framework that allows you to build **pure native mobile apps** by reusing your existing **web development skills**.

So the obvious answer is No, you can't use any libraries that targets HTML (until you want to run your whole app inside a WebView).

NativeScript for Vue / Angular allows you to reuse all the core features comes with the framework to build a native app. You have to get familiar with cross platform UI components provided in box with NativeScript and the CSS attributes supported by platform to build your app.

Comment: Does the nativescript has some Material theme? Or does it have only one possible look nowadays?

Comment: You have to think from native app perspective. Most Android UI components are more material by default, for example the alert dialogs, ripple effects etc., None of these are default in iOS neither you can't make a iOS dialog to look similar to Android / Material without putting major effort.

But the good part is you have lot of plugins that can bring you those effects without too much of work. For example, you can use this plugin - https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-ripple to bring Android like ripple effect in iOS.

Comment: Again there is other plugin here https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-cfalert-dialog to make dialogs more fancy. Apart from existing NativeScript plugins there is whole lot of pod / gradle libraries for iOS / Android which can be just reused in a NativeScript project.

Comment: How does [this](https://developer.android.com/design/material/index.html) fit in? I looks like plain android native apps can be "materialized", but as for nativescript, if it wants to stay cross platform it is limited by the available native components of various platforms. So far I don't se any other possibilities to develop android material app, then native android SKD or hybrid webview based application, am I right?

Comment: NativeScript doesn't restrict you from using any of the native features, it may be iOS / Android you can do anything you could do in Objective C / Java. Material design is something Google Introduced, so obviously its very well implemented in Android (by default). Apple has it's own guidelines, it won't give you material (by default). Still you can match the UX in iOS with decent efforts, using the plugins available in market already.